# JSON into listview in xamarin forms, does not order in the list after the json

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I work with a database (json) that i load into a listview.

My json that I recieve is ordered the way I want it but as group the different categoryID's into different categories it does order itself like the json looks like (ordered with end_date first to last) but instead it loads into the list into the different categories.

This is how I recieve my data:

```
static public async Task<JObject> getEvents ()
    {
        var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();

        var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync ("http");

        var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

        var jsonResult = JObject.Parse (resultString);

        //this below does not effect how the list turns out. I have tried it
        /*
        JArray sorted = new JArray (jsonResult ["records"].OrderBy (obj => obj ["end_date"]));

        jsonResult ["records"] = sorted; */


        return jsonResult;

    }
```

The listview & items:

```
public class items
    {
        public string eventTitle { get; set;}
        public string endDate { get; set;}
    }

new List <items> theListOne = new List <items> ();
new List <items> theListTwo = new List <items> ();

string idcategory;

async void loadList ()
{

var getItems = await phpApi.getEvents ();

  foreach (var currentitem in getItems["records"]) {

                idcategory = currentitem ["id_events_categories"].ToString (); 


if (idcategory == "1") { 

                    theListOne.Add (new items () {

                        eventTitle = currentitem ["title"].ToString (),
                        endDate = currentitem ["end_date"].ToString (),
                    });
    }

if (idcategory == "2") { 

                    theListTwo.Add (new items () {

                        eventTitle = currentitem ["title"].ToString (),
                        endDate = currentitem ["end_date"].ToString (),
                    });     
                  }

        }

var result = theListOne.Concat(theListTwo);

eventsList.ItemsSource = result; //eventsList is my listview x:name

}
```

So now in the list, the items stack themselves up in their respective category (1 & 2) and not via the JSON-order.

How could I adjust this so the items orderes the same way as the json? I want to order the list after "end_date" just as the json is.

My json looks like this and I have ordered it via the end_date but as I mentioned above. It doesn't order itself in the listview the same away after I separate them into different categories.

UPDATE: IT orderes but only on that particular list and not together like I want it to. So theListOne orders itself after the dates but only within the items in theListOne and the same thing with theListTwo.

```
{
  status: "ok",
    records: [
                { 
                  title: "Test",
                  end_date: "2016-05-22 16:00:00",
                  id_events_categories: "1",
                }

            ]
}
```

Comment: if the initial json is already ordered, then iterating through it and assigning to two groups shouldn't change the relative order of the items.

Comment: Can you make a [simple but complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem that we could compile and test, ideally a console app?  As it is we just have code fragments that give some idea of what you are doing, but do not compile standalone and so cannot be debugged.

Comment: I am not sure how i can describe it more. The json does not order itself in the listview the same way the json is ordered. Is there a way I can make a frontend order-code?

Comment: why don't you just sort the theListOne and theListTwo by the date before assigning them to your listview?

Comment: that could be a solution. i am not quite sure how that would look though. i concat the lists together and then add them as a itemssource to the list if that has any effect on the json

Comment: @medvedo - it's not that we are asking you to describe it further.  We're asking for fully compilable code that we could test ourselves.  For instance, there's no definition of `theListOne`.  I could assume that it's a `List<items>`, but maybe it isn't -- maybe it's a `HashSet<items>`.  If so, then that's the bug.  With a complete [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's not necessary for us to make any assumptions.

Comment: Thanks alot for reminiding me! Forgot about the lists. I added them now and alos the "Concat" that I use to merge the different lists.

Comment: Are `theListOne` and `theListTwo` [local variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691170.aspx) or [class members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx)?

Comment: `new List <items> theListOne = new List <items> ();` and 
`new List <items> theListTwo = new List <items> ();` I updated the code as well. I concat them together in the end and use them together as the itemssource for my listview

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with a simple test app.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/H0Qqua.  All I can guess is that, if `theListOne` and `theListTwo` are fields not local variables, their values are getting changed before the call to [`Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) is evaluated - remember, LINQ uses lazy evaluation.  Try doing `var result = theListOne.Concat(theListTwo).ToList();` instead to see if that helps.

Comment: I have tried with ToList as well. Doesn't change the order though :(

Comment: Okay. It orders after date (like the json does) but it only orders via that partricular list. So it only order via that particular list. So theListOne orders after its dates but only the items in theListOne and the same thing with theListTwo

Comment: So Group1 is sorted by date, and then Group2 is sorted by date?  That is exactly what I would expect - I'm not sure how else you possibly expect it to work?

Comment: Yes, but I want them to be sorted by date together. Instead of them being sorted in two different categories and then they get sorted by date. I want them to "mesh" together and all of the lists should sort after all of their dates.

Comment: then why are you doing all of this work to break them into groups if you just want them all sorted together in a single list?

Comment: I want to separate them for several reasons. The first reason is to handle them later in groups (if the user wants to filter that particular group with that ID and another reason I want to break them into groups is so I can add a unique image to that partricular group.

Comment: hvaughan is getting close to something below I think. I am currently trying to merge it with a previous code you gave me (`JArray sorted = new JArray (jsonResult ["records"].OrderBy (obj => obj ["end_date"]));`) but of course without the jarray. I think that might be the answer if I get the code to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
var result = theListOne.Concat(theListTwo);

eventsList.ItemsSource = result.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

*Edit: Sorry I am an idiot. Try this:

```
var result = theListOne.Concat(theListTwo);

eventsList.ItemsSource = result.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x.endDate)).ToList();
```

Comment: Error: `Cannot convert ProjectName.ProjectPage.items expression to type 'string'`

Comment: @medvedo Where is that happening? What variable is being assigned to a `string`? The error message alone is not very helpful.

Comment: This code right here gives the error: `eventsList.ItemsSource = result.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x)).ToList();`

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks alot dude!!

Comment: @medvedo Sure thing. Glad it help. Sorry to steal it from the commenters.